# Access the Source Control Explorer in TFS from C#.net code

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, source-control-explorer

Here is the code which I have written to access the Projects and the team, but it shows some error. I want to access the project and then the Source Code present in the Source Control Explorer in the Project/Team.

```
            Uri _serverUri = new Uri("MyURI");
            string _teamProjectName = "MyProject";

            TfsTeamProjectCollection collection =
                TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(_serverUri);

            // Retrieve the project URI. Needed to enumerate teams.
            var css4 = collection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
            ProjectInfo projectInfo = css4.GetProjectFromName(_teamProjectName);

            // Retrieve a list of all teams on the project.
            TfsTeamService teamService = collection.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            var allTeams = teamService.QueryTeams(projectInfo.Uri);
            allTeams.ToList().ForEach
            (
            allteams => { Console.WriteLine(allteams); });
```

The error which it shows is "The type or namespace 'Core' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server

I also want to access the source control, so if anyone can help me with both of my issues.

Comment: You may should remove the using-Directive "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core"

Comment: @Oswald Thanks, that solved the issue but still can you please help me to reach to the source control ??